# Realization of uniform volume charge density

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, experimental-technique, experimental-technology

A sphere with uniform volume charge density is often considered as an example in E&M. Is this a useful fiction for testing students or are there any techniques to induce a uniform volume charge density in a body? Are there any materials which naturally form a uniform volume charge density when charge is deposited?